# Minecraft server when there are no players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does time pass on a Minecraft SMP server if nobody is logged on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27557/does-time-pass-on-a-minecraft-smp-server-if-nobody-is-logged-on)

What happens in the minecraft server when there are no players? Will my wheat still grow? Will animals continues to spawn?

Answer (score 4):

In general, chunks only 'update' when they are loaded, and they are only loaded when a player is in that chunk.

However, there is a bukkit plugin called ['Forever A-load'](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admin-fix-foreveraload-v1-02-keep-your-chunks-forever-a-loaded-1337.28665/) you can get for a bukkit enabled server that can enable certain chunks to always be active so things like wheat will grow, redstone will always be active and the like.