# Bukkit mod that can schedule loading and running chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have a Bukkit server between friends and we don't log on too often; maybe every week or so.  It's a bit discouraging to log on and see that none of our farms have grown, none of our auto harvesters have harvested anything.

I don't want to leave the chunks running all the time (I also haven't been able to find a good mod for this in any case) because my server is running on a shared machine and I don't want to always spend server resources on it.

Is there a way to maybe schedule the chunks loading?  Maybe ... for one hour a day?

Comment: I'd love to see this type of bukkit plugin :) It may also be worth asking if spawn chunks are loaded when no-one is logged on

Comment: [Does time pass on a Minecraft SMP server if nobody is logged on?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27557/does-time-pass-on-a-minecraft-smp-server-if-nobody-is-logged-on)

Comment: You need to have a fake player in those chunks to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Bukkit has a few, mostly outdated, plugins that allow for the loading of chunks when there are no players nearby, [ChunkLoader](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/chunkloader/) is one of them, albeit still experimental(use at your own risk).  If you can and are willing to, you may change your server to a forge, chicken_bones has created a mod named [ChickenChunks](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-162-smp-chickenbones-mods/) which uses craftable blocks to load chunks.  Neither mod has the ability to schedule loaded chunks, but ChickenChunks can be configured to only be active while a (any) player is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish chunk loading without a mod, is to use hopper loops as discussed in this question:  [Can I use a hopper loop as a chunk loader?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125290/can-i-use-a-hopper-loop-as-a-chunk-loader?lq=1)

Starting and stopping the server automatically is a different issue.  I've not dug into that, however, I would look to see if there are command line options to minecraft that would enable it to be started from a script.