# Will a piston continue moving in a server once everyone leaves, or commence moving when everyone rejoins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-redstone

I'm making a prison in a minecraft realm and found a post with a piston moving a block in circles, will the piston continue moving when everyone leaves?

Comment: I assume the pistons will not move, except for in spawn chunks (because the rest of the chunks aren't loaded unless someone is nearby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Time in the sense of day/night cycle and weather passes while no one is on, however in all other senses time doesn't pass in a given chunk unless a player is online and nearby enough (although for a small set of chunks near the default spawn, "nearby enough" is anywhere in the Overworld). [Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27557/does-time-pass-on-a-minecraft-smp-server-if-nobody-is-logged-on)

So the piston should stop once everyone leaves.

> Flying machines / redstone contraptions with slime/honey blocks at chunk borders break when chunks are loaded/unloaded. [Source](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/issues/3439)

When someone joins back and the piston is in loaded chunks, and if on chunk borders, they break, else they continue moving.

Comment: Just replying to DialFrost, would that mean that once someone rejoins the server, the pistons resume movement?

Comment: No, it will resume movement once the chunk is loaded. That will only happen when someone is close enough. If the piston is part of a complicated machine and the machine is running when everyone leaves there's a good chance the machine will break. @Cup